# App crashes whenver I try to run, do tell the mistake

Tags: java, android-studio

Here is the code

```
private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
private ActivityMainBinding binding;
private Button b1;
private Button b2;
private Button b3;
private Button b4;
private Button b5;
private Button b6;
private Button b7;
private Button b8;
private Button b9;
private Button b10;
private Button b11;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    b1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openfindme();
        }
    });
    b2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openalarm();
        }
    });
    b3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openscheduler();
        }
    });
    b4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
    b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openstatus();
        }
    });
    b5 = findViewById(R.id.button12);
    b5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openmain();
        }
    });
    b6 = findViewById(R.id.button);
    b6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openmain();
        }
    });
    b7 = findViewById(R.id.button7);
    b7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openmain();
        }
    });
    b8 = findViewById(R.id.button10);
    b8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openmain();
        }
    });
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

    Spinner myspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names));
    myadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    myspinner.setAdapter(myadapter);

}

public void openfindme(){
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FindMe.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
public void openalarm(){
    Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this,alarm.class);
    startActivity(j);
}
public void openscheduler(){
    Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Scheduler.class);
    startActivity(k);
}
public void openstatus(){
    Intent l = new Intent(MainActivity.this,status.class);
    startActivity(l);
}
public void openmain(){
    Intent m = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(m);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

}

Here is the error

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2022-06-17 12:59:46.506 5024-5024/com.example.icompanion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.icompanion, PID: 5024
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.icompanion/com.example.icompanion.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2925)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3060)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1818)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
        at android.app.Activity.requireViewById(Activity.java:2678)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requireViewById(ActivityCompat.java:368)
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:58)
        at com.example.icompanion.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:105)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3060) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1818) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2022-06-17 12:59:46.517 5024-5024/com.example.icompanion I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5024 SIG: 9
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity

Comment: If you use binding you don't have to use `b1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);` in this way. To access to the button1 for example, you must access it using  your binding like this- > `b1 = binding.button1;`. Change all the `findViewById` statements with bindings as in the example, then compile it again.

Comment: Looks like this line of your code is causing the problem: `NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);`

Comment: For better coding: When you use view binding you don't even have to keep view references in your activity because the binding implementation is already keepin all the view references. Just access them like `binding.button1.setEnabled(true)`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).